# When I call tranfer_from function, remix saids gas limit exceed

Tags: gas, assembly

I am owner of the token contract, And when I call transfer_from() function,
remix saids gas limit exceed. my gas limit is 300000.

this is same contract, and call transfer_from() successfully.
"https://bloxy.info/tx/0x1a172bb8cc2926f54eb5403c35aa01761eb2f7a6c20c3abfa1a804f919051a33"

but my contract is same, transaction is not wokring successfully.
"https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa5558694cdc190f1f2c5a7e4e2adbeb130ce127ad15be854f49502856c87351a"

i don't know what is metter.

this is my full code.
thanks

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
library SafeMath {

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;       
    }       

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}


contract Ownable {
    address public owner;
    address public newOwner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        newOwner = address(0);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() { //owner
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    modifier onlyNewOwner() {
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(_newOwner != address(0));
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }

    function acceptOwnership() public onlyNewOwner returns(bool) {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract Pausable is Ownable {
  event Pause();
  event Unpause();

  bool public paused = false;

  modifier whenNotPaused() {
    require(!paused);
    _;
  }

  modifier whenPaused() {
    require(paused);
    _;
  }//pasue check 

  function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
    paused = true;
    emit Pause();
  }

  function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
    paused = false;
    emit Unpause();
  }
}

contract ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}


interface TokenRecipient {
    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; 
}


contract abc is ERC20, Ownable, Pausable {

    uint128 internal MONTH = 30 * 24 * 3600; // 30day,1month

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    struct LockupInfo {
        uint256 releaseTime;
        uint256 unlockAmountPerMonth;
        uint256 lockupBalance;
    }

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 internal initialSupply;
    uint256 internal totalSupply_;

    mapping(address => uint256) internal balances;
    mapping(address => bool) internal locks;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) internal allowed;
    mapping(address => LockupInfo) internal lockupInfo;

    event Unlock(address indexed holder, uint256 value);
    event Lock(address indexed holder, uint256 value);
    event Burn(address indexed owner, uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        name = "abc";
        symbol = "abc";
        decimals = 18;
        initialSupply = 1000;
        totalSupply_ = initialSupply * 10 ** uint(decimals);
        balances[owner] = totalSupply_;
        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, totalSupply_);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        if (locks[msg.sender]) {
            autoUnlock(msg.sender);            
        }
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);


        // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _holder) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_holder] + lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        if (locks[_from]) {
            autoUnlock(_from);            
        }
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);


        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
        require(isContract(_spender));
        TokenRecipient spender = TokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }//approve
    }

    function allowance(address _holder, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_holder][_spender];
    }

    function lock(address _holder, uint256 _amount, uint256 _releaseStart, uint256 _releaseRate) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(locks[_holder] == false);
        require(balances[_holder] >= _amount);
        balances[_holder] = balances[_holder].sub(_amount);
        lockupInfo[_holder] = LockupInfo(_releaseStart, _amount.div(100).mul(_releaseRate), _amount);

        locks[_holder] = true;

        emit Lock(_holder, _amount);

        return true;
    }

    function unlock(address _holder) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(locks[_holder] == true);
        uint256 releaseAmount = lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance;

        delete lockupInfo[_holder];
        locks[_holder] = false;

        emit Unlock(_holder, releaseAmount);
        balances[_holder] = balances[_holder].add(releaseAmount);

        return true;
    }

    function getNowTime() public view returns(uint256) {
      return now;//now
    }

    function showLockState(address _holder) public view returns (bool, uint256, uint256) {
        return (locks[_holder], lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance, lockupInfo[_holder].releaseTime);
    }

    function distribute(address _to, uint256 _value) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[owner]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(owner, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function distributeWithLockup(address _to, uint256 _value, uint256 _releaseStart, uint256 _releaseRate) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        distribute(_to, _value);
        lock(_to, _value, _releaseStart, _releaseRate);
        return true;
    }

    function claimToken(ERC20 token, address _to, uint256 _value) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        token.transfer(_to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        address burner = msg.sender;
        balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
        totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.sub(_value);
        emit Burn(burner, _value);//burn
        return true;
    }

    function isContract(address addr) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint size;
        assembly{size := extcodesize(addr)}
        return size > 0;
    }

    function autoUnlock(address _holder) internal returns (bool) {
        if (lockupInfo[_holder].releaseTime <= now) {
            return releaseTimeLock(_holder);
        }
        return false;
    }

    function releaseTimeLock(address _holder) internal returns(bool) {
        require(locks[_holder]);
        uint256 releaseAmount = 0;
        // If lock status of holder is finished, delete lockup info. 
        if (lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance <= lockupInfo[_holder].unlockAmountPerMonth) {
            releaseAmount = lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance;
            delete lockupInfo[_holder];
            locks[_holder] = false;
        } else {            
            releaseAmount = lockupInfo[_holder].unlockAmountPerMonth;
            lockupInfo[_holder].releaseTime = lockupInfo[_holder].releaseTime.add(MONTH);
            lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance = lockupInfo[_holder].lockupBalance.sub(releaseAmount);
        }
        emit Unlock(_holder, releaseAmount);
        balances[_holder] = balances[_holder].add(releaseAmount);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Remix's message is most likely misleading. Did you make sure to call `approve` first?

Comment: IF 

`A is From in transfer_from`
`B is To in transfer_from (owner)`


, Doesn't the Approve function require A to execute?
I do not have ownership of the wallet in A, only ownership of B.

As far as I know, the approve function knows to give "spender" permission to the asset of the "runner". Am I wrong?